# Authenticate MongoDB along with Robomongo

Tags: mongodb, authentication, robo3t

> I'm currently using Robomongo when accessing my mongodb database. I
>   have created a admin account on mongodb who has admin access to any
>   db. I would like to be able to ONLY login with the credentials of the
>   admin account. Now I can just login as "guest" without giving in any
>   credentials, I've already looked at the authentication mongodb files
>   but these seem only to authenticate using the cmd tool on the mongodb
>   itself. How can I make that my admin account can only login using the
>   Robomongo?
>
> Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In your mongodb conf file add this line "authorization: enabled"